# lua substr function. param encoding

Tags: encoding, lua

I need to use in lua an analog of the function php - mb_substr, where there is - bitwise step.
Example in php - mb_substr($value, 0, 32, '**8bit**');
is there anything like that lua?

edit:
bit of a bit - bitwise step

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879997/lua-string-char-encoding

Comment: What if I need to get a bit of a bit?
string = $J�R[Tߑ��ǢN�m3�d�@�;@���+m��Q�8�os�E��~8f124d90c959e36d81464562fe0393e2

Comment: what is "a bit of a bit" supposed to mean?

Comment: Can you explain what *exactly* you are trying to do?  It seems confusing to be doing bitwise operations while discussing a *character* function.